# Orbeon Forms: is there a way to disable the processing of external entities to avoid XXE attacks?

Tags: orbeon, xxe

After a PenTest, the Security Team found a possibility of XXE attack when submitting an Orbeon form through an HTTPS request, from our web application.

They were able to intercept the following XML:

```
<!DOCTYPE event-request [<!ENTITY nbsp "&#160;">]>
<xxf:event-request xmlns:xxf="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xforms">
    <xxf:uuid>8a89ecf50184eb16f5671301691e0d9457568667</xxf:uuid>
    <xxf:sequence>16</xxf:sequence>
    <xxf:action>
        <xxf:event name="xxforms-blur" source-control-id="pd-section-per-sonalData-control≡xf-474≡pd-birthName-control"/>
        <xxf:event name="xforms-focus" source-control-id="pd-section-per-sonalData-control≡xf-474≡pd-birthName-control"/>
        <xxf:event name="xxforms-value" source-control-id="pd-section-per-sonalData-control≡xf-474≡pd-birthName-control">Tester&lt;</xxf:event>
        <xxf:event name="xxforms-blur" source-control-id="pd-section-per-sonalData-control≡xf-474≡pd-birthName-control"/>
    </xxf:action>
</xxf:event-request>
```

And inject a new external entity, `<!ENTITY test "My-OwnEntity">`, by manipulating the request. THis was the XML submitted to the server:

```
<!DOCTYPE event-request [<!ENTITY nbsp "&#160;"><!ENTITY test "My-OwnEntity">]>
<xxf:event-request xmlns:xxf="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xforms">
    <xxf:uuid>8a89ecf50184eb16f5671301691e0d9457568667</xxf:uuid>
    <xxf:sequence>16</xxf:sequence>
    <xxf:action>
        <xxf:event name="xxforms-blur" source-control-id="pd-section-per-sonalData-control≡xf-474≡pd-birthName-control"/>
        <xxf:event name="xforms-focus" source-control-id="pd-section-per-sonalData-control≡xf-474≡pd-birthName-control"/>
        <xxf:event name="xxforms-value" source-control-id="pd-section-per-sonalData-control≡xf-474≡pd-birthName-control">My-OwnEntity</xxf:event>
        <xxf:event name="xxforms-blur" source-control-id="pd-section-per-sonalData-control≡xf-474≡pd-birthName-control"/>
    </xxf:action>
</xxf:event-request>
```

The request is then processed correctly and the value of the entity appears in the response returned by the server.

According to them, two approaches/solutions are suggested:
1. Create a whitelist of allowed entities; or
2. Prevent the processing of these external entities in all cases.

But I couldn't find in the Orbeon documentation a way to implement any of these solutions (the second one would be more appropriate to my concrete case). Does anyone know how to do it or has experienced a similar situation and handled it differently?

Thank you.

Comment: As mentioned in my answer below, XML entity parsing in Orbeon Forms isn't a security risk since version 4.0, but of course just let me know if I missed anything, or misunderstood your question. ‑Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Processing entities while parsing XML *can* be a security problem, for instance allowing a [billion laughs attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Billion_laughs_attack) denial-of-service attack, but it is not necessarily one if done properly. Orbeon Forms sets up Xerces, used for XML parsing, with a `SecurityManager` ([#686](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/686)) since version 4.0, and in that context entity parsing is safe, as far as I know.

Comment: Hello @avernet and thank you for your reply. I'll get back to the Security Team with this information. I believe they haven't actually tried to attack one of our test systems, but I'll ask them to do that and see what happens. After that, I'll come back to this post to let you know about the results and accept your answer. Thanks.

Comment: Sounds good @d.lacher, and of course feel free to let me know if they still have any concern about this. ‑Alex

Comment: @d.lacher Just curious: have you heard anything back from your security team about this, or are they happy with what Orbeon Forms does?

Comment: They have tested and were unable to create a billion-laughs attack. Therefore, Orbeon worked just as you describer and I am accepting your answer as the solution for this question. @avernet

Comment: @d.lacher OK, excellent. And thank you for confirming this indeed works as expected!